# Callback on a website not working using CefSharp in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Im trying to get a callback using cefsharp on a website i dont own.

On the launching of my application i bind the tag "cb"

```
chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("cb", new BoundObject(), true);

public class BoundObject
{
     public void dosomthing()
     {
          MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
     }
}
```

Using the following javascript script i add an object to the website:

```
function insertBefore(el, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode);
}

var newEl = document.createElement('div');
newEl.className = 'exampleclass';
newEl.innerHTML = '<a onclick="cb.dosomthing();">Do somthing</a>';

var ref = document.getElementById('example-tab');

insertBefore(newEl, ref);
```

I perform this using:

```
ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded
```

Then when i click the added in element with the text "Do somthing", nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: None, the callback just doesn't happen, and my application doesnt know the button is clicked.

Comment: Try giving `alert('Hello')` instead of `cb.dosomething()` ... if this works, then probably `cb` is not found.... Is there a way to see `console` of this browser ? I believe `console` will definitely have some error.

Comment: You have registered your object,  you haven't actually bound it in JavaScript based on the example you've provided see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cefsharpbindobjectasync

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/2febd683b9e9f08e19aab68b575bae8b349c0ba5 for an example

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript binding requires that you call `CefSharp.BindObjectAsync` in javascript before you can access the object. I also recommend wrapping your code in an anon closure when it's more than a single line.

An example would look something like

```
(async function()
{
    await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("cb");

    //Object with name cb will have been bound, you can now access

    function insertBefore(el, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode);
    }

    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    newEl.className = 'exampleclass';
    newEl.innerHTML = '<a onclick="cb.dosomthing();">Do somthing</a>';

    var ref = document.getElementById('example-tab');

    insertBefore(newEl, ref);
})();
```

Also `MessageBox.Show` should be called on the `UI` thread, the `BoundObject.dosomething` method will be called on a background thread. A simple solution is to pass a reference to your `Form/Window/Control` (not sure if you are using `WinForms` or `WPF`, so I cannot say exactly) then Invoke the call back onto your `UI` thread. For testing purposes what you have should be ok, if you want to do anything more serious then you should change your code.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `CefSharp.PostMessage` which is new in version `75`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221 for an example.